# Unable to get external files dir. External Storage State is mounted on Android

Tags: android, file, kotlin

I have been struggling with creating a File on API 23 of Android.
I am getting the following error:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: cannot get external files dir, external storage state is mounted
```

I am trying to setup a Voice Recognizer, and for that I have to open the file for the words. I set up the Voice Recognizer this way.

```
     private fun runRecognizerSetupAsync(): String? {
     try {
        Log.d("Voice",  "${isExternalStorageWritable()}  gg ")
         val assets = Assets(activity)
         val assetDir = assets.syncAssets()
         setupVoiceRecognizer(assetDir)
     } catch ( e : IOException){

         Log.v("VoiceCommands", "$e + Error ")
         return e.toString()

     }
    return null
}

private fun setupVoiceRecognizer(assetsDir: File) {
        speechRecognizer = SpeechRecognizerSetup.defaultSetup()
            .setAcousticModel(File(assetsDir, "es-ptm"))
            .setDictionary(
                File(assetsDir, "cmudict-es.dict")
            )
        .recognizer
        speechRecognizer.addListener(this)

        // Create keyword-activation search.
        //recognizer.addKeyphraseSearch(KWS_SEARCH, KEYPHRASE);

        // Create your custom grammar-based search
        val activationWords = File(assetsDir, "activation.gram")
        speechRecognizer.addKeywordSearch(ACTIVATION_SEARCH, activationWords)

    }
```

It works properly on most phones, but there are some exceptions that throws this error.
Every bit of guidance is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance for taking the time. :)

Comment: setupVoiceRecognizer(assetsDir: File) Show in your code how you call this function. Show how you set up the File parameter.

Comment: Alright. Done my friend. I would appreciate the help.

Comment: `val assetDir = assets.syncAssets()` I have no idea which directory that would be. Please tell full path.